# Migration task failed at 'load data local infile' while migrating the data from RDS MySQL to Azure Database for MySQL using Attunity Replicate MSM

Tags: amazon-aurora, attunity, azure-mysql-database

I try to migrate data from **Amazon RDS MySQL** to **Azure Database for MySQL** using **'Attunity Replicate for Microsoft Migrations**(Replicate MSM)'. 
For this I setup the Replicate MSM tool on a Windows 10 machine locally, then I define & test the source & target database endpoints eg. RDS as source and Azure as target, *install the required mysql, odbc drivers and enable binary logging, local-infile parameters on both the databases*. But now when I run the migration task it only create the schema's of migrated tables on target db and failed at 'load data local infile' command.
Here's the stack trace:

```
00014468: 2019-06-20T11:17:41 [SOURCE_UNLOAD   ]I:  Unload finished for table 'TestDb'.'Employee' (Id = 1). 2000 rows sent.  (streamcomponent.c:2892)
00014968: 2019-06-20T11:17:41 [TARGET_LOAD     ]I:  Loading table 'migrationtesting'.'Employee' with parallel threads  (odbc_endpoint_imp.c:5256)
00014968: 2019-06-20T11:17:41 [TARGET_LOAD     ]I:  Use parallel load thread pool with '3' threads  (csv_target.c:280)
00014968: 2019-06-20T11:17:42 [TARGET_LOAD     ]I:  Load finished for table 'TestDb'.'Employee' (Id = 1). 2000 rows received. 0 rows skipped. Volume transfered 904960  (streamcomponent.c:3116)
00014968: 2019-06-20T11:17:43 [TARGET_LOAD     ]E:  Failed to execute statement: 'load data local infile "C:\\Program Files\\Attunity\\ReplicateMSM\\data\\tasks\\Aws2Azure\\data_files\\1\\LOAD00000001.csv" into table `migrationtesting`.`Employee` CHARACTER SET UTF8 fields terminated by ','  enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n'( `id`,`name`,`gender`,`mobile`,`city` ) ;' [1022502]  (ar_odbc_stmt.c:4349)
00014968: 2019-06-20T11:17:43 [TARGET_LOAD     ]E:  RetCode: SQL_ERROR  SqlState: HY000 NativeError: 1148 Message: [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver][mysqld-5.6.39.0]The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version [1022502]  (ar_odbc_stmt.c:4355)
00007376: 2019-06-20T11:17:43 [TASK_MANAGER    ]W:  Table 'TestDb'.'Employee' (subtask 1 thread 1) is suspended  (replicationtask.c:2050)
00014968: 2019-06-20T11:17:43 [TARGET_LOAD     ]E:  Failed to start load process for file '1' [1022502]  (csv_target.c:1350)
00007376: 2019-06-20T11:17:43 [TASK_MANAGER    ]I:  All tables are loaded. Full load only task is stopped  (replicationtask.c:2992)
00014968: 2019-06-20T11:17:43 [TARGET_LOAD     ]E:  Failed to load file '1' [1022502]  (csv_target.c:1418)
00014968: 2019-06-20T11:17:43 [TARGET_LOAD     ]E:  Failed to load data from csv file. [1022502]  (odbc_endpoint_imp.c:5331)
```

According to Azure docs:

> LOAD DATA INFILE is supported, but the [LOCAL] parameter must be
>   specified and directed to a UNC path (Azure storage mounted through
>   SMB).

if this is the solution then kindly explain how to implement it.

**Note: MySQL Server version on both RDS and AZURE is 5.6**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error logs suggest that you're using v5.3 of MySQL ODBC Driver in which the **LOAD DATA INFILE** functionality is disabled by default, to enable this we need to explicitly set the value of **ENABLE_LOCAL_INFILE** to 1.
In Attunity Replicate for Microsoft migrations, you have to enable this flag for your **Target** database endpoint, you can enable it by following these steps...

> - Open the settings of **target** Endpoint.
> - Goto **Advanced tab > Internal Parameters**.
> - Add search key **additionalConnectionProperties** and hit Enter. (it's case-sensitive,so just copy/paste the same)
> - You can see a new key has been created under internal parameters, type the value for this newly created key as: **ENABLE_LOCAL_INFILE=1;**
> - **Save** and then **Reload** your task.

**Credits:** Official Attunity Community/Support team for Microsoft Migrations